# Ubuntu Unity: Integrating with global menu bar

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-12.04

Where can I begin investigating on how to add menu bar integration for a non-Gtk app when running under Ubuntu Unity? A few quick Google searches with keywords like "ubuntu unity menu bar integration" did not reveal anything interesting.

This is good to know if one wants to create a menu for, for example, an SDL app, or if I wanted to integrate GNUstep's menus into Unity.

---

Looks like I need to investigate "dbusmenu" project and the "com.canonical.dbusmenu" interface. Does anyone have nice docs on that?

---

Some useful code is available in [this code](http://java-swing-ayatana.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10/trunk/jayatana/jayatana/org_java_ayatana_ApplicationMenu.c) that integrates Java Swing menus with DBusMenu. It's from the [java-swing-ayatana](http://code.google.com/p/java-swing-ayatana) project which appears to aim at improving integration of Swing apps into Ubuntu.

---

I wrote some code in [MiniDbus-Menu](https://bitbucket.org/ivucica/minidbus-menu/overview) repository on BitBucket. (Yes, I accidentally inconsistently named the repository. Sue me. :-) It comes with some notes on my explorations in README.md.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work yet, so the question remains open. **I'd love to know what I did wrong in my code!**

Answer (score 3):

You can read this question in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com):

- [How to add support for the global menu to a python non-GTK, non-QT app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98692/how-to-add-support-for-the-global-menu-to-a-python-non-gtk-non-qt-app)

Ted Gould, the author of dbusmenu-glib, gives some pointers on how to hook up your app menu to the global menu bar. I could rephrase his answer but I think it is preferred that you actually read the linked answer.

Comment: I've looked at it, and it's been somewhat helpful. Unfortunately, it still doesn't provide a good example of non-Gtk code in C, and I didn't manage to get a menu displayed in the menubar. In fact, I'm not exactly sure why the answer is accepted on that question - it's a nice pointer in the right direction, but doesn't provide something... complete. I've made some progress on my minimal example that avoids Gtk and updated the question. Code sadly doesn't work yet. https://bitbucket.org/ivucica/minidbus-menu/overview

Answer (score 0):

For getting this to work with Java Applications, check out solution 2 on this blog:

[Integrating Java Swing Applications with Unity Global Menu](http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/integration-of-java-swing-applications-with-unity-global-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/)